# Is returning a refrence to an enum variant in Rust a good idea?

Tags: rust

I'm making a Tic-Tac-Toe game in Rust as a beginners project and was working on calculation the state of the game(won, draw, etc.) when I ran into this issue. I first wrote the following code:

```rust
fn status(&self) -> Status {
    if Board::has_won(self.x_board) {
        Status::Won(true)
    } else if Board::has_won(self.o_board) {
        Status::Won(false)
    } else if self.is_full() {
        Status::Draw
    } else {
        Status::None
    }
}
```

I then modified it to return a refrence:

```rust
fn status(&self) -> &Status {
    if Board::has_won(self.x_board) {
        &Status::Won(true)
    } else if Board::has_won(self.o_board) {
        &Status::Won(false)
    } else if self.is_full() {
        &Status::Draw
    } else {
        &Status::None
    }
}
```

I did this to link the lifetime of self and the returned value together so if the state of the board changed the reference to status could no longer be used.

I then tried this code:

```rust
fn status(&self) -> &Status {
    let status;
    if Board::has_won(self.x_board) {
        status = Status::Won(true)
    } else if Board::has_won(self.o_board) {
        status = Status::Won(false)
    } else if self.is_full() {
        status = Status::Draw
    } else {
        status = Status::None
    }

    &status
}
```

And it resulted in a compiler error saying it cannot return a referenced to owned data. Why doesn't the first snippet have this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that the first snippet is subject to [lifetime extension](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-understand-temporary-lifetime-extension-correctly/70503), while the second is a reference to an explicit local variable and hence already has an explicit lifetime. The rules for lifetime extension are complex, so I'll let someone else discuss the specifics of that. Instead, I want to pose a slightly different design.

What you're doing is admirable. In fact, it's awesome. I'd never thought of tying a status variable like that to a data structure with references. That being said, you're lying to Rust a *bit* here, and we can get the behavior you want a bit more directly.

Basically, you have a `Status`. It's a value, it's not borrowed, and pretending that it's borrowed is just a bit awkward. It's not wrong, just awkward. But you want it to *semantically* behave like it's borrowed, even though it's not. We can use a [`PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html) to do that.

Consider this. Leave your `Status` enum alone. Make it `Copy` and `Clone`, since it's nice and simple, and never take references to it. It can still be used sensibly as an independent data structure, provided you never assume that it's tied to any particular board.

Now, when you *want* to tie it to a particular board, use a new struct which I'll call `BoardStatus`.

```
struct BoardStatus<'a> {
  status: Status,
  _phantom: PhantomData<&'a Status>,
}
```

A `BoardStatus` really is just a `Status`. Its only non-zero-sized field is a `Status`, so the representations of the two should be identical. But it also has a [`PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html). `PhantomData<T>` is a zero-sized type (meaning it takes up no space at runtime) that *pretends* to contain a `T` for lifetime purposes. So `BoardStatus` is a `Status` (an owned status value, no borrows) that *pretends* to be borrowed for duration `'a`. Then your `status` method can have this return type.

```
fn<'a> status(&'a self) -> BoardStatus<'a>
```

or, with [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-elision.html)

```
fn status(&self) -> BoardStatus<'_>
```

That way, there's a difference between the `Status` enum, which is independently testable and has no additional baggage; and the `BoardStatus` struct, which is *still* just a status but is explicitly tied to a board.

The best part is: this all has *zero* overhead. There's no actual pointer at runtime, so `BoardStatus` is exactly as efficient as a `Status` at runtime, with no indirection. A truly zero-cost abstraction.

Comment: Someone else said the first snippet may be due to the variants having the lifetime `'static`. Thanks for you suggestion of the `PhantomData`!

Comment: I think that the first reference example works, not because of _lifetime extension_, but because of _[rvalue static promotion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1414-rvalue_static_promotion.md)_, similar phenomenon but not exactly the same.